# Inconsistent behaviour with concurrent postgresql access through node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

A rather trivial use case of node.js and postgresql puzzles me.

It seems that the results from the first query executed by this code linger and are erroneously included in the results array from the second query.

Expected output:

```
running queries ---------------
[ { name: 'Company 0' } ]
[ { id: 0, company_id: 0 }, { id: 1, company_id: 0 } ]
```

Usual output:

```
running queries ---------------
[ { name: 'Company 0' } ]
[ { name: 'Company 0' },
  { id: 0, company_id: 0 },
  { id: 1, company_id: 0 } ]
```

Occasionally I get the correct result. Below the code, include a 'fix' which ensures I always get the correct result:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var connectionString = require('./dbconfig.js');



var doQuery = function(queryString) {

    // Get a Postgres client from the connection pool
    pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {

        results = [];
//         results.push(queryString); // PART OF 'FIX'

        var query = client.query(queryString);

        // Stream results back one row at a time
        query.on('row', function(row) {
            results.push(row);
        });

        // After all data is returned, close connection and return results
        query.on('end', function() {
            client.end();
//             results.splice(0, 1);  // PART OF 'FIX'
            console.log(results);
        });

        // Handle Errors
        if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        }

    });
};

var company_id = 0;

console.log('running queries ---------------');

doQuery('SELECT companies.name  FROM companies WHERE companies.id = '+company_id+';');

doQuery('SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.company_id = ' + company_id + ';');
```

If anyone is interested in attempting to reproduce this (and assuming it is not a silly coding error by me) I will gladly provide the rest of the code to do so.

Comment: Looks to me like `results` is global, so both calls to `doQuery` push onto the same array.

Comment: Oh crap. Completely missed that one. Thanks. You can submit your comment as an answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

JavaScript is a terrible language (see my comment for solution).